# TortoiseSVN - Ignore empty directories?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When commiting my working copy of a repository using GitHub and TortoiseSVN, everything works dandy. That is, until I have an empty directory. Is there a way to make TortoiseSVN ignore these empty directories when commiting, or even delete them? I don't always know where they are, so it's not a simple "add to ignore list" Or "just delete it yourself", as they are always created (I am using Unity engine).